# How to stop sprite animation at start in Flutter Flame game engine

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to render this card and the first time it's loaded, the animation start once. What I want is the default there is no animation happen. Does anyone know how to make this happen?

```
    class Card extends AnimationComponent {
      Card(width, height)
          : super.sequenced(width, height, 'card.png', 5,
                textureWidth: 144.0, textureHeight: 220.0, loop: false);

    }
```

```
    class GameScreen extends BaseGame {
      GameScreen({@required this.size}) {
        add(Card(0,0));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/6b3f519d443f9c011084e51ecf828dfa13eb7467/lib/components/animation_component.dart#L61-L64), you'll able to use [`Animation`](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/6b3f519d443f9c011084e51ecf828dfa13eb7467/lib/animation.dart) to control the frame.

For simple, just don't call `update` and keep rendering, the frame index will not be updated.

```
  void update(double dt) {
    clock += dt;
    elapsed += dt;
    if (isSingleFrame) {
      return;
    }
    if (!loop && isLastFrame) {
      onCompleteAnimation?.call();
      return;
    }
    while (clock > currentFrame.stepTime) {
      if (!isLastFrame) {
        clock -= currentFrame.stepTime;
        currentIndex++;
      } else if (loop) {
        clock -= currentFrame.stepTime;
        currentIndex = 0;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

So you could just override the `update` method to get the controll of sprite animations.

Comment: thanks @tokenyet, I have overrided the update method and it's work